# Delete an empty folder through FTP using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I'm trying to use the FTPWebRequest in VB.net to remove an empty folder.

```
Dim request = WebRequest.Create(FTPURL + directory)
request.Method = WebRequestMethod.FTP.RemoveDirectory
request.GetResponse
```

However I keep getting the exception "The requested FTP command is not supported when using HTTP proxy."  I know its possible because I can do it if I use FTP through windows command line.

```
ftp FTPURL
user username password
rmdir directory
```

or

```
rm directory
```

Both rm and rmdir work.  Is there something else I need to do to make it work?

edit:
My overall goal is to be able to get, send, and delete files from the server, I am currently using ncftpget an ncftpput to do this.  ncftpget allows me to remove all files in a folder but doesnt allow me to delete the folder itself, which is why I'm trying to find a work around.

I also dont want to have the username and password in a text document on the user's PC, so I dont want to make a batch file with all the steps to use the command line ftp.

Comment: Try setting the Proxy property of the request to Nothing.

Comment: I tried that, I then get "Unable to connect to the remote server".